# Uniform convergence over unit interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous, differentiable functions on $[0,1]$ converging pointwise to $f$ such that:

- $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,\lambda]$ for all $0<\lambda<1$
- $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $[0,1)$

Is it true that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]?$ What if $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ for some convergent $\sum a_k?$

**Edit:** first part solved, thanks guys. Any help on the second part would be greatly appreciated.

---

Initial try:

I think the answer is yes, but I am having trouble proving it. I tried this:

Taking $\epsilon>0$ we can find $\delta>0$ such that $|1-x|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(1)-f(x)|<\epsilon/3$. Take $\xi\in (1-\delta, 1]$. It would be enough to show that, for some $N$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [\xi,1]$ and $n\geq N$. We could choose $N$ so that $\forall n>N:$

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \underbrace{|f(x)-f(1)|}_{<\epsilon/3}+\underbrace{|f(1)-f_n(1)|}_{<\epsilon/3}+\underbrace{|f_n(1)-f_n(x)|}_{<\epsilon/3 ?}<\epsilon ?$$

I can't see how to use the rest of the information to restrict the last modulus, or whether this is even a good route to take.

Comment: @A little lime: I believe Normal Human's comment was automatically generated, as many questions are posted with excessive and distracting punctuation.  In this case, your use of "???" was actually quite appropriate and did not detract from your question at all (in my opinion), and you should feel free to restore it.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample: Let $\eta$ be a nontrivial smooth function supported in $[0,1]$. Then

$$f_n(x) = \eta( 1- nx)$$

has support in $[1-\frac 1n, 1]$. $f_n$ converges uniformly to the zero function on $[0,\lambda]$ for all $\lambda <1$, and converge pointwisely to the zero function on $[0,1]$. But the convergence is not uniform.

However, if

$$f_m(x) = \sum_{n=0}^m a_n x^n,\ \ \ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

and $\sum a_n$ exists, then the assertion is true.

*Proof*: 
Let $s_n = a_0+ a_1 +\cdots a_n,  s_{-1} = 0$. Note that $s_n \to s = \sum a_n$.  Now we have

$$f_m(x) = \sum_{n=0}^m a_nx^n = \sum_{n=1}^m (s_n - s_{n-1})x^n = (1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} s_n x^n + s_m x^m$$

This means

$$\begin{split}|f_m(x) - f_m(1)| &= \left|  (1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} s_n x^n + s_m x^m - s_m \right|\\
&=\left| (1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} s_n x^n - s_m(1-x) \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} x^n\right| \\
&= (1-x) \left| \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (s_n -s_m) x^n \right|.
\end{split}$$

Now as $s_n \to s$, then $\{s_n\}$ is Cauchy and so there is $K$ so that $|s_n - s_m| < \epsilon/6$ for all $m, n \ge K$.

Now for all $m \ge K$,

$$\begin{split} (1-x) \left| \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (s_n -s_m) x^n \right| &=(1-x) \left| \sum_{n=0}^{K} (s_n -s_m) x^n  +  \sum_{n=K}^{m-1} (s_n -s_m) x^n\right| \\
&\le (1-x) M_K + \frac{\epsilon }{6}(1-x) \sum_{n=K}^{m-1} x^n \\
&\le (1-x) M_K + \frac\epsilon 6(1-x) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \\
&= (1-x) M_K + \frac\epsilon 6
\end{split}$$

for all $x\in [0,1]$. (Note that the argument does not work for $x=1$, but the inequality is satisfied trivially in that case). In particular, if $x$ is close to one so that $|1-x |< \frac{\epsilon}{6M_K}$, then

$$|f_m(x) - f_m(1)| <\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

for all $m\ge K$ and $x$ close to $1$. This is precisely what you need to show the uniform convergence.

Remark: The above proof is a small modification of the proof of [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) that I found in Rudin's PMA.

Comment: "if x is close to one" not "closed to one".Trivial typo.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $f_n$ is a triangular spike of height $1$ on the interval $[1-1/n,1-1/(n+1)].$ ( I know $f_n$ is not differentiable on $[0,1),$ but it should get you thinking.)